# RT 1020 board uses 64K "SRAM_DTC" to store .bss data, my application requires more

Tags: microcontroller, sram, gcc

I am trying to port my application to an [NXP (RT 1020) board](https://www.nxp.com/products/processors-and-microcontrollers/arm-microcontrollers/i-mx-rt-crossover-mcus/i-mx-rt1020-crossover-mcu-with-arm-cortex-m7-core:i.MX-RT1020).

I understand that this board doesn't have internal flash, and therefore runs from SRAM. It uses "SRAM_DTC" (tightly coupled data) and "SRAM_ITC" (tightly coupled instruction) to manage this.

In MCUXpresso I can see the memory layout:

[image]

When I compile my application, the linker gives an error mentioning that the .bss section will not fit in its SRAM_DTC section.

> region `SRAM_DTC' overflowed by 12172 bytes

I am trying to understand if this "SRAM_DTC" section is **mandatory** in order to run my application on this board. I tried simply deleting the SRAM_DTC section, and run the application, but that won't compile in MCUXpresso :

> board/board.c:198: undefined reference to `__base_NCACHE_REGION'

When I also delete the NCACHE_REGION in memory configuration, the board no longer boots up. I can recover from that following the troubleshooting steps [here](https://mcuoneclipse.com/2017/12/16/mcuxpresso-ide-v10-1-0-with-i-mx-rt1052-crossover-processor/).

I read all I can find on this SRAM_DTC/ITC/OC topic. I still can't figure out of I can "move" the .bss section to some place in external SRAM.

My questions:

- can somebody confirm (or deny) if it's possible to solve my problem by moving .bss section from "SRAM_DTC" to "BOARD_RAM"?
- is this doable from Xpresso (linker scripts are generated for me, I can't make tweaks as far as I know)?

Some background info I found on SRAM_DTC/ITC/OC [here](https://www.element14.com/community/roadTestReviews/2713/l/nxp-imx-rt1050-ev-kit-and-display-review) and [here](https://community.nxp.com/t5/MCUXpresso-Community-Articles/Tutorial-MCUXpresso-SDK-with-Linux-Part-3-RAM-and-XiP-Code-on-i/ba-p/1131041).

Comment: I do not have direct experience with your board, however you should be able to change the linker settings to place various memory areas elsewhere. Note that you need to ensure your startup code has configured the external memory controller in order to have it operational. Also the performance will be much slower and there may be reordering issues that NXP aren't too forthcoming in acknowledging (at least with the RT1062).

Answer (score 2):

For those who are interested in the same topic and having a hard time to find documentation:

A lot of DTC/ITC information is explained here:
https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN12077.pdf

DTC indeed is optimized for data, where ITC is optimized for instructions. I still haven't found definitive documentation that claims that ITC is only to be used in for code which is executed from SRAM.

In my case, my application needed more DTC SRAM than the default 64KB available.

Therefore I followed this manual eventually:
https://community.nxp.com/t5/i-MX-RT-Knowledge-Base/Reallocating-the-FlexRAM/ta-p/1117649

Writing to 3 different registers the memory configuration can be changed. I changed my memory config to 0B ITC, 192KB DTC and (the minimum allowed) 64KB for OC.

The OC is used for their default shipped boot loader, hence it can't be fully removed.